# nHibernate and QueryOver to serialize for processing by a Web Service

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, nhibernate-criteria

Is it possible to generate a query via nHibernate, serialize the `Criteria`/ `DetachedCriteria`, send it to an external service for processing, and have the results almost replace the `QueryOver`, or at least be injected into it?

So, something like:

```
return _session
     .QueryOver<VirtualFolder>()
     .Where(m => m.Name = "FolderName" & m.Parent = folderParent)
     .SingleOfDefault();
```

Would result in the query effectively being passed to a remote service...

Thanks,

Kieron

#### Edit

I'm asking specifically about being able to serialize the queries because we have a few shared services. One of the areas of use has direct access to the database, the other does not. So it would be nice to be able to use the same service, with a different implementation of the QueryOver...

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but i think it can do a lot of security problems, this feature allows to execute any query, and it can be very dangerous.

Comment: That's very true, but that aspect is entirely in hand though our existing internal service.

Answer (score 0):

@Anton has a very good point.
I would recommend creating your own *query objects* and serializing those.
[This post](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) by Ayende can get you started.